# What is the Android Studio keyboard shortcut for Package Explorer?

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I've tried googling, and so far the closest answer is this one:
[Android Studio is driving me nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/U7yU2mz5L0c)

However, it's not really a keyboard shortcut, and besides, the "Project Pane" isn't always visible. (If anyone knows how to make it permanently visible, please tell me.)

What I do is search "Project" on the quick search bar, click on it to make it appear, and then switch to Package Explorer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Alt+1 toggles the pane in question - not sure though if there is a short cut to toggle between project and packages there

Comment: This drove me nuts for close to half an hour.Thanks

Comment: I use AS 3.0.1 on win 7, alt 1 does nothing. I see empty window, but my App opened

Answer (score 0):

I have created my shortcut key for Project Explorer in my Android Studio by following steps:

1) Go to **Window** -> **Preferences**,

2) On the left pane Select **General**,

3) Inside **General** tab click on **Keys** option,

4) Now at right side select **Show View(Package Explorer)** after scrolling the list

5) After clicking on **Show View(Package Explorer)** there is an option below called **Binding**. Click on that, edit the text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>(tilde sign) (this is a shortcut key for Project Explorer. You can also create your own.).

Now whenever you want to show project explorer, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

Comment: Sorry, there's no Preferences in my Window menu. I tried quick searching Preferences, but couldn't find it. I'm using AS 5.5 btw, sorry I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply clicking "Project" on the left-hand toolbar works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use cmd + 2 and I press 3 times, that way I can toggle between the project file structure and the actual files without closing the pane. That's for mac, as for windows I would think you could use the equal toggle shortcut which I believe is alt + 2.